# How can I train a Chan Vese contour to segment specific tones?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, contour, image-segmentation

I am using a Chan Vese active contour to segment some of my Ultrasound images.

I need to find a way to train this contour segment specific grey tones, without having to threshold the image.

I know it utilizes an energy minimization function based on a Mumford Shah technique. I guess there must be a way to tune some of its regulatory parameters and train it to be selectively.

It is also somehow a mathematical problem.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance

I am using a Chan Vese contour

Comment: Not really, you just try and test until you find a number you like for the parameters

Comment: Do you know exactly what parameters to play with?